# How to multiply a number after each 60 minute automatically

Tags: javascript

I want to multiply a number with '31' after each 60 minutes
suppose i have multiplied 2 * 31 = 62
then again after 60 minute the value will be 62*31 = 1922

How to do it in javascript ?

Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use setInterval. But do you want to do it in browser? I doubt anynone will have the page open for 60 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are better ways to do what you're asking for. But if you want to do it in browser (for practice purposes, I am assuming), you can use `setInterval` like this :

```
var number = 2;
function multiply() {
    alert(number * 31);
    number = number * 31;
}

setInterval(multiply, 5000);  // Change 5000 to whatever time interval you want.
```